# How to handle keypress event properly in Ember js 3.13

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm new to Ember & I want to catch a global key press event and handle it in my component.

After a lot of web crawling I did it the old fashion way with global `window.onkeydown = this.handleKeyPress` & at the handleKeyPress function i did some code and call `this.movePlayerInDirection` but now my 'this' is the window.

```
onKeyPress(e, comp) {
    let keyCode = e.keyCode;`

    if (keyCode === KEY_LEFT ||
        keyCode === KEY_UP ||
        keyCode === KEY_RIGHT ||
        keyCode === KEY_DOWN) {
        let direction;

        switch(e.keyCode) {
            case KEY_LEFT:
                direction = {x: -1, y: 0}
                break;
            case KEY_RIGHT:
                direction = {x: 1, y: 0}
                break;
            case KEY_UP:
                direction = {x: 0, y: -1}
                break;
            case KEY_DOWN:
                direction = {x: 0, y: 1}
                break;
        }
        this.movePlayerInDirection(direction);
    }
}
```

1. Is this the best way to catch this event? (the ember way)
2. How do i reach the component functions from the window scope?

UPDATE:

Based on the answer below I just added `window.onkeydown = this.onKeyPress.bind(this)` and it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no special ember way to do this. However there are addons like `ember-keyboard-shortcuts`.

However generally using `window.addEventListener` is not a bad idea. However you need to do two things:

1. cleanup the listener when the component gets destroyed
2. bind the event to the function context

For a classic component this could look like this:

```
Component.extend({
  init() {
    this.boundOnKeyPress = this.onKeyPress.bind(this);
  },
  didInsertElement() {
    window.addEventListener('keypress', this.boundOnKeyPress);
  },
  willDestroy() {
    window.removeEventListener('keypress', this.boundOnKeyPress);
  },
  onKeyPress() {
    ...
  }
})
```

Comment: not working... the keypress event doesn't get fire against (or catched )

Comment: i tried something based on your solution and it worked only when i set the event listener in this syntax: `window.onkeydown = this.onKeyPress.bind(this)`

Comment: you should always prefer `addEventListener` and not assign the `on{eventname}` properties, because assigning the property will overwrite a previous event listener.
Also this definitly works. If it doesnt, do you have a reproduction with ember-twiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use [ember-keyboard](https://github.com/briarsweetbriar/ember-keyboard) addon for this job. This has a very nice explanation for features it offers in the the below link,
https://github.com/briarsweetbriar/ember-keyboard

Firs you need to add mixin to your component,

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import { EKMixin } from 'ember-keyboard';

export default Ember.Component.extend(EKMixin, {
  . . . .
});
```

and then need to set `keyboardActivated` property to true. The below code will be called after init method.

```
activateKeyboard: Ember.on('init', function() {
    this.set('keyboardActivated', true);
  })
```

You shall import the required event

```
import { keyPress } from 'ember-keyboard';

onKeyPressHandler: Ember.on(keyPress('Escape'), function() {
        // console.log('escape button pressed');        
    }),
```

In your case, if you want an event to fire for every keypress, then simply don't provide a keystring to keyUp or keyDown. This can be a handy way to trigger events for large ranges of keys, such as on any alphanumeric keypress. For instance:

```
import { getCode } from 'ember-keyboard';

triggerOnAlphaNumeric: Ember.on(keyUp(), function(event) {
  if (/^Key\w(?!.)/.test(getCode(event))) {
    ...
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

We wrote [ember-key-manager](https://github.com/IcarusWorks/ember-key-manager) because it provides a cleaner interface than any of the other key-event addons. Specifically, it provides a service so you can inject it anywhere and are not stuck using mixins (which are now deprecated).